# filling specific values in columns based on filtering strings in another column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

Assume that we have the following dataframe

```
df1
Full code    Semi-code    Score
1111-ABC     1111         1 
0000-ABC     0000         2
AP00-ABC     AP00         1
1234-XYZ     1234         2
```

and I want to create the following dataframe

```
df2
Semi-Code    ABC         XYZ
1111          1          nan
0000          2          nan
AP00          1          nan
1324          nan        2
```

Basically the new dataframe takes the Semi-Code for df1 and then"

- creates 2 new columns (1 for each of the codes that you see in the Full code thus ABC and XYZ
- then it places the score under the correct column and nan in the other

Any ideas how can I do it without using for loops?

Answer (score 0):

This is a variation on a [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
(df.assign(col=df['Full code'].str.extract('([^-]+$)', expand=False))
   .pivot('Semi-code', 'col', 'Score')
   .reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
)
```

output:

```
  Semi-code  ABC  XYZ
0      0000  2.0  NaN
1      1111  1.0  NaN
2      1234  NaN  2.0
3      AP00  1.0  NaN
```

If order is important, use [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) with `sort=False`:

```
(df.assign(col=df['Full code'].str.extract('([^-]+$)', expand=False))
   .reset_index()
   .pivot_table(index='Semi-code', columns='col', values='Score', sort=False)
   .reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
)
```

output:

```
  Semi-code  ABC  XYZ
0      1111  1.0  NaN
1      0000  2.0  NaN
2      AP00  1.0  NaN
3      1234  NaN  2.0
```